# axvline and axhline in a loop for multiple subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 16 subplots and want to include following in each subplot:

```
ax1.axvline(x=0.5, ymin=0.0, ymax=1.0, color='k', linestyle='--', alpha=0.3)
ax1.axhline(y=0.5, xmin=0.0, xmax=1.0, color='k', linestyle='--', alpha=0.3)
```

Running a loop to have them for all subplots seems more feasible rather to have 32 lines, but simple string concatenation isn't working such as

```
for i in xrange(1,17,1):
    # then try to use i for each ax -- this isn't practical
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, could you post more of your code?  What do you mean by "simple string concatenation" ?

Answer (score 5):

You kinda got everything written already...

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots(17)

for i in range(17):
    ax[i].axvline(x=0.5, ymin=0.0, ymax=1.0, color='k', linestyle='--', alpha=0.3)
    ax[i].axhline(y=0.5, xmin=0.0, xmax=1.0, color='k', linestyle='--', alpha=0.3)
```